# Convert Marklogic query to Postgresql query

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, marklogic

Please can some one tell clarify me on the start and page_length in marklogic function,
search:resolve(
$xml-query, $options, $from_row, $num_fetch
)
If I convert above to Postgresql query,
then here "from_row"  is nothing but starting from this row say 10th row and "num_fetch" is nothing but fetch 20 rows data starting from 10th rown in Postgresql ?.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Marklogic documentation is clear.. start is a positive int defaulting to (1) and pageLenght is number of records.   So start: 1 and pageLenght:10 will return records 1-10...  Start 23 and pageLenght 7 will return 23-29.. pageLenght 0 returns no results

Comment: @DavidEnnis__17llamas__ Thank you for the response. So the below Postgresql                select * from table  WHERE column='somevalue' OFFSET 1 ROWS Limit 5                            is equivalent to above marklogic.